# How to simply build an external project with cmake externalproject_add

Tags: c++, cmake

I've got a library I want to integrate into an existing cmake build. All cmake has to do is go into that directory, run "make", perform install steps as I lay out (probably just a copy to an included binary directory), and then keep doing its thing. Cmake continues to step on my toes trying to create directories and guess at pathnames.

The command in the base CMakeLists.txt is:

```
ExternalProject_Add(mylib BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib/sdk BUILD_COMMAND make)
```

However, when I try to build, cmake complains about:

```
    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2630 (message):
  No download info given for 'mylib' and its source directory:

   /home/brydon/build/myTarget/existingLib/mylib-prefix/src/mylib

  is not an existing non-empty directory.  Please specify one of:

   * SOURCE_DIR with an existing non-empty directory
   * DOWNLOAD_COMMAND
   * URL
   * GIT_REPOSITORY
   * SVN_REPOSITORY
   * HG_REPOSITORY
   * CVS_REPOSITORY and CVS_MODULE
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3236 (_ep_add_download_command)
  CMakeLists.txt:83 (ExternalProject_Add)
```

Why is it jumping at all of these directories? I don't understand what CMake is trying to do here - all it needs to do is run `make` in the directory that I very clearly spefified as the build dir.

I have tried using SOURCE_DIR but then I get an error that there is no CMakeLists.txt in that directory, which again is not what I want.

How can I get cmake to very simply use an existing makefile, and nothing more?

Comment: `BUILD_DIR` is not correct or at least when I search the documentation for BUILD_DIR I get no hits: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) I think you wanted `BINARY_DIR` instead of `BUILD_DIR`

Comment: `BUILD_DIR` is not the name of a parameter to [`ExternalProject_Add`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

Comment: My mistake - I typoed that trying to put it back in. I've edited the question with the correct line and the resulting error

Comment: You need to set `SOURCE_DIR` and set `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` to an empty string (according to the documentation)

Comment: @AlanBirtles That did it. I was trying to figure out how to provide the source directory without having cmake try to do the configure. The empty `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` is the trick here. Which documentation specifies this?

Comment: The documentation for `ExternalProject_Add` that we linked above, search for `non-CMake`

Comment: Thank you - was having trouble finding it in there. If you'd like to post an answer I think it would add value - I didn't find something similar on SO already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't downloading code then `SOURCE_DIR` needs to be set to an existing directory containing your library.

If you aren't using cmake then you need to set `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` to an empty string as stated in the [`ExternalProject_Add`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) documentation.